# IF/IFS in Google Drive - Check if multiple cells are empty

Tags: google-sheets, documentation, google-docs

I'm trying to add periods or commas to help make our data entry folks lives a little easier when they work with our Google Sheets.

Right now we check a few cells to see if a comma or a period should be added after each tag. The tags are housing and transportation. If there are no responses for those cells they should be blank and the tag before it should have a period. Otherwise there should be a comma to show there is another tag coming.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!G2:G), "", IF('Form Responses 1'!G2:G = "0", "No", 'Form Responses 1'!G2:G) & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!H2:H)," housing. ", " housing, ")) & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!H2:H), "", 'Form Responses 1'!H2:H & " transportation, ") & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!I2:I), "", "" & 'Form Responses 1'!I2:I))
```

I've got this working for the first case but in the last case I cant seem to make it work. I want to check if anything is added for the final response. If there is something added then the transportation tag needs to have a comma. If not it can have a period. But if there is nothing in the following cell there should be nothing. I've only been able to get it to work where Transportaion. is in every cell by default.

This is closer but still wrong.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!G2:G), "", IF('Form Responses 1'!G2:G = "0", "No", 'Form Responses 1'!G2:G) & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!H2:H)," housing. ", " housing, ")) & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!H2:H), "", 'Form Responses 1'!H2:H) & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!I2:I), IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!G2:G), IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!H2:H), "", " transportation. ")," transportation. "), " transportation, ") & IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!I2:I), "", "" & 'Form Responses 1'!I2:I))
```

Is there another Google Docs operator that I'm not aware of that would make this easier?

[image: Screenshot of the google sheet]

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, data, data types or layout; and we don't know your business or your end goal. So while what you describe in your post may make perfect sense to you (who *can* see everything and *does* know the full scope), from "out here," it's murky.

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Great points. Just added a screenshot of the cells I'm working with.